# Gamma traceless

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, dirac-matrices, trace, higher-spin

I read this [Under what conditions is a vector-spinor gamma trace free](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95970/). And also read many papers about higher spin, but no one explains why irreducible spinor is gamma traceless spinor? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: $\gamma^\mu \psi_\mu$ has *no free* Lorentz indices, whereas it has free spinor indices, the ahllmark of a spinor, so spin 1/2. What is the problem? [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/119699/66086) looks fine.

Comment: I read that fermions transform as reducible ((n+1)/2,n/2)+(n/2,(n+1)/2) (which is equivalently as direct product of n (1/2,1/2) and Dirac (1/2,0)+(0+1/2) rep )representation because this representation has space inversion as Weinberg says in their QFT Vol 1, page 233.  For example n=1. We have (1/2,1/2)x((1/2,0)+(0,1/2))=(1,1/2)+(1/2,0)+(1/2,1)+(0,1/2) it is REDUCIBLE. He also says (in footnote) that doubling of j=1/2 removes by imposing Dirac equation remaining divergenceless condition (not completely, but intuitive clear- removing ghosts). Question is how we remove one of two j=3/2?

Comment: Right question is how gamma tracelles removed one j=3/2 ?

Comment: I really have no idea what you are trying to say. Perhaps if you refashioned your question, *without reference to Weinberg's book*!, and asked just one question... Most texts on supergravity are vastly clearer on this.

Comment: [Same answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168875/decomposition-of-the-gravitino-into-helicity-pm-frac32-and-pm-frac1).